# New to Pi: "Association request to driver failed"

Tags: wifi, connection

I literally just got started with my pi tonight. So I am that new. Any instructions you give me should assume I know nothing.

I'm trying to connect to wifi and getting the mentioned error on the "wpa_gui" program on Rasbian(OS version unknown to me, Raspberry Pi Model 2 B+, I think). I have an edimax wifi dongle.

Knowing this is networking it could be any number of things. So suggestions?

My "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" file reads as follows:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="*"
    psk="*"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth-alg=Open
}
```

* replaced for privacy, but known to be correct.

I wanted to configure my pi as a router before thanksgiving so my grandma's house will have wi-fi while I'm up there. So a speedy fix is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplictae: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5361/i-can-not-get-my-wifi-connection-to-work

Comment: Possibly, but the level that question is written at is already WAY over my head.

Comment: But one of the answers tells me something else: "Specifically, the "at" symbol and quotation mark are reversed on a UK keyboard, so the "at" symbol in my password came out as a quotation mark, which the config file certainly didn't like. :)" But that does tell me something else about which I have problems: how to take it off the uk keyboard setting? I now know why the symbols were reversed when typing!

Comment: I don't know when thanksgiving is, but gather it is soon. Trying to learn how to run the Pi in a few days, in particular setting up as a router, is unrealistic. Buy a router - it would be cheaper. PS ignore the Possible duplicate it is obsolete.

Comment: I already have a pi. Free is cheaper. Even if I can't get it to where I want to be right away, I'll still need to fix this issue(connecting to wifi in general) to get anywhere on any project, so I still want the help.

Comment: Try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921

Comment: I already tried [wifi with gui](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-raspbian) (yes, this is the gui I have, I got pi a few months ago and finally got around to opening it) and [command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) Since the gui version in the suggested question is a newer one, it may not be applicable to me.